# Error in implementation of kotlin libraries

Tags: android, kotlin

when i build rocket chat andrroid code, i am getting this error.

Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

core/build.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


  android {
  compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/core.kotlin_module'
    exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation libraries.kotlin
implementation libraries.coroutines
implementation libraries.lifecycleExtensions
kapt libraries.lifecycleCompiler
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71"}

  repositories {
             mavenCentral()
            }
```

Comment: implementation "<insert dependency here>".

NOT

implementation <insert dependency here>

Notice, the lack of " in the second example (i.e. just look at your gradle file... it has discrepancies...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line instead:

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The extensions you're using aren't getting detected by the `core/build.gradle`. There are a couple ways to solve this.

You could parse the dependencies from the `dependencies.gradle` where they're defined. Looking at the Rocket.Chat.Android example, the extensions look like this:

```
 ext {
    versions = [
            kotlin                : '1.2.61',
            coroutine             : '0.25.0',
            ...

            lifecycle             : '2.0.0', 
            ...
]
    libraries = [
            kotlin                : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${versions.kotlin}",
            coroutines            : "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:${versions.coroutine}",
            ...
            lifecycleExtensions   : "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:${versions.lifecycle}",
            lifecycleCompiler     : "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:${versions.lifecycle}",
            ...
    ]
}
```

and your `core/build.gradle`'s dependency block would look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.61"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.25.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71"
}
```

Alternatively, you could just apply the `dependencies.gradle` file to `core/build.gradle` and I think it should detect the extra properties defined there.

Adding `apply from: "../dependencies.gradle"` to your `core/build.gradle` is what I'm talking about.